# Facing issue while coping some contents from the file and sending the contents in a mail using Perl

Tags: perl, file, email

I am facing some issues while copying some lines of data from a file into an array and then using the command `print MAIL "$line" ;` to send a mail with those file contents using Perl.

When i receive the mail with the contents of the file, there are some unexpected characters in between the text which was not there in the file itself.

I am not sure why this is happening because it seems simple.

```
my @mail_contents=<MAIL_CONTENT>;
chomp(@mail_contents);
my $line="";
foreach $line (@mail_contents)
{

      if($line =~/some pattern matching/)
      {
            $var1 = $line;
      }
      if($line =~/some pattern matching/)
      {
           $var2= $line;
      }
}

my @arr_var1=split(/&/,$var1);
my @arr_var2=split(/&/,$var2);

foreach my $OR (@arr_var1)
{
       print MAIL "$OR";
}
foreach my $FTD (@arr_var2)
{
       print MAIL "$FTD";
}
```

---

File content:

```
<br> <font size=5> My name is Maxintown </font> <br> <br> <table> <tr> <td> <font color=blue> How are you today </font> </td> <td> <font color=blue> How do you do </font> </td> </tr>
```

Mail Content:

```
My name is Maxintown

How do are yo!u today

How do you d!o
```

---

Clearly you can see ! as an unwanted character. But in file it is not there. So i am not sure what is happening. Please provide suggestions.

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting in your question a little, but I'm unsure of if the HTML you put in your question is actually in your file or not. If it isn't, please edit the question and remove it. Keep the four-space indent so it stays formatted "code style" (or use the code button)

Comment: Also the regular expressions in your example code do not correspond to your sample data.

Comment: Yes there is few mistake but the point is iam getting some abnormal characters in between text. Example is there to show you the difference. Please suggest how to remove it.

Comment: If the HTML is all on one long line, the symptoms are consistent with the MTA breaking up your lines every *n* characters, and adding a bang where a break was inserted. I would expect *n* to be closer to 1,000 but in any event, try breaking your lines on whitespace, or using quoted-printable encoding and adding `=\n` every 72 characters (this translates to an invisible line break which is removed when the QP is decoded).

Comment: After reading your question carefully, I still don't have a clue what you're talking about. For example I can't see how your example data relates to the code snippet. Also your code snippet is too heavily "sanitised" to be able to get any idea of what is supposed to be going on (for example, what is "some pattern matching").

Answer (score 2):

Throw away your code and start over. Use [Courriel::Builder](http://p3rl.org/Courriel%3a%3aBuilder) to generate MIME email messages and [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender) to send them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting problems sending data through e-mail, one approach would be to send your data base64 encoded. This can be done easily using functions `encode_base64` and `decode_base64` from the builtin module [MIME::Base64](http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html).

So when putting data **into** an e-mail message, pass it through `encode_base64`, and when getting data **out of** an e-mail message, pass it through `decode_base64`. This will work for data which is composed of bytes.

If your data contains codepoints outside the byte range (0 to 0xFF), then you will need to encode it down to bytes first, so you might want to consider something like `encode_utf8` from the builtin module [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html), then use `decode_utf8` to get your original data back again.

For example:

```
print $outgoingMessage encode_base64(encode_utf8($some_utf_8_string));
```

(`$outgoingMessage` is the file handle for the outgoing message.)

You should make sure that in your e-mail message the Content Type is appropriately flagged as such, for example:

```
From: ...
To: ...
Subject: ...
Date: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

V2VsbCBkb25lLCB5b3UndmUgc3VjY2Vzc2Z1bGx5IGRlY29kZWQgdGhlIGJhc2U2NCBkYXRhIGlu
IG15IHN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tIGFuc3dlci4gVGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBv
dmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZy4gTm93IGlzIHRoZSB0aW1lIGZvciBhbGwgZ29vZCBtZW4gdG8gY29t
ZSB0byB0aGUgYWlkIG9mIHRoZSBwYXJ0eS4=
```

You should choose an appropriate Content Type for your data and put that in the Content-Type record. So if you know that your content is HTML, and you have used `encode_base64`, then the Content-Type record should read:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

Comment: Recommending those low-level modules makes only sense when the OP is already intimately familiar with mail and MIME, both RFC and [in the dirty reality](http://youtube.com/watch?v=JENdgiAPD6c), which obviously isn't the case.

Comment: It's a fine line. One might suggesting something which is the 'right' answer (say, using something like Courriel), BUT this might be too abstract for the OP to understand, in which case they might blow off the answer and think that it was 'all too difficult', or the OP might not be able to use CPAN, or the OP might not be very good with OO Perl. Alternatively, we could suggest a few procedural bits from core modules which are only one step beyond what the OP already seems to be familiar with. This might then give the OP the power to make one step forward.

Comment: Also, it's handy for people to have some idea of how MIME works 'underneath' all these nice abstractions. By doing stuff 'manually' first, people can get some idea of what's going on at the nuts and bolts level. Once they're happy with that, they can then decide they don't need to think about it any more and move up to a higher level of abstraction. The point here is to avoid creating programmers who only know how to push broad buttons and don't know how anything works underneath.